# how to add radio button to each item in a list sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

```
               {
               itemId   : 'shippinglist',
               title    : 'Shipping Services',
               height   : 500,
               layout   : 'fit',
               collapsed: true,
               items: [{
                       xtype    : 'list',
                       itemId   : 'list2',
                       store    : 'Checkout',
                       itemTpl  : '<div>Shipping Type: {shipping_type}</br>Amount: ${amount}</div>',
                        }]
```

the above is one of the items in the accordion view. my problem is I want to add a radio button to each item in the list so that I will know what shipping type the user has selected. Can I add radio button in itemTpl inside div.please help me on this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, http://jsfiddle.net/jdflores/9Lrb8/1/, you can see how it's done for an Ext.view.DataView in ExtJS. The 'list' in Sencha Touch is a descendant of this class. Anyway, the technique can be applied to both because it's mostly is based on css and framework selectors.

```
.x-item-selected {
    background : #ffc url(../path/to/a/checked/checkbox) no-repeat 5px center;
}
```

Comment: Hey Thank you so much,this is very helpful for me...now I am getting list with buttons but the check boxes are not working,I think that is not a big issue .. I am working on that ... Thank u again